# Searching for event and event immediately preceding

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is how the table is laid out (just showing pertinent rows):

```
id      timestamp                     eventno
A       2020-01-21 13:02:00.000       300010
B       2020-01-21 13:02:45.000       300010
E       2020-01-21 13:02:50.000       300010
B       2020-01-21 13:02:90.000       300020
M       2020-01-21 13:03:56.000       300010
```

I would like to extract all occurrences of eventid 300010 that were immediately followed by eventid 300020 - the catch is my table has 800 different ids and I need it to look for the immediate preceding event for the same id.

So my results would look something like this:

```
B       2020-01-21 13:02:45.000       300010
B       2020-01-21 13:02:90.000       300020
```

I really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: ms sql server mgmt studio

Comment: FYI SSMS isn't the DBMS its just a client interface.

Comment: When you say "I need it to look for the immediate preceding event for the same id", I'm assuming only for eventno 300010 & 300020. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, timestamp, eventno
  FROM (SELECT id, 
               timestamp, 
               eventno,
               LAG(eventno) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY id 
                    ORDER BY timestamp) previous_eventno,
               LEAD(eventno) OVER (
                     PARTITION BY id 
                     ORDER BY timestamp) next_eventno
          FROM table
        ) AS x
 WHERE (x.eventno = 300020 and x.previous_eventno = 300010)
    OR (x.eventno = 300010 and x.next_eventno = 300020);
```

Comment: @Scrattle, change the alias to something else than inner, if not it will generate errors. Change to x, and the query is perfect

Comment: @zip Oh. Is that special for SQL Server?

Comment: I guess, sql says: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'. But once changed to some else, it works great

Comment: Thank you for testing it :) I only have a SQLite.

Comment: worked like a champ...u helped me out and taught me something - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it like this:
Give me, for the same id, event 300010 with an event 300020 coming after but no event between the two

```
     WITH CTE AS
(                          
SELECT 'A'   AS id,    '2020-01-21 13:02:00.000'  AS timestamp,     300010 AS eventno
UNION SELECT'B',       '2020-01-21 13:02:45.000',       300010
UNION SELECT'E',       '2020-01-21 13:02:50.000',       300010
UNION SELECT'B',       '2020-01-21 13:02:90.000',       300020
UNION SELECT 'M',      '2020-01-21 13:03:56.000',      300010
)



    select *
    from CTE a
    inner join CTE b
        on a.eventno = 300010 and b.eventno = 300020 and a.timestamp < b.timestamp and a.id = b.id                   
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from CTE c
            where c.timestamp > a.timestamp
            and c.timestamp < b.timestamp and c.id = b.id
        )
```

This one returns

```
id  timestamp   eventno id  timestamp   eventno
B   2020-01-21 13:02:45.000 300010  B   2020-01-21 13:02:90.000 300020
```

If you want the one row below the other:

```
     WITH CTE AS
(                          
SELECT 'A'   AS id,    '2020-01-21 13:02:00.000'  AS timestamp,     300010 AS eventno
UNION SELECT'B',       '2020-01-21 13:02:45.000',       300010
UNION SELECT'E',       '2020-01-21 13:02:50.000',       300010
UNION SELECT'B',       '2020-01-21 13:02:90.000',       300020
UNION SELECT 'M',      '2020-01-21 13:03:56.000',      300010
)


select a.*
from CTE a
inner join CTE b
    on a.eventno = 300010 and b.eventno = 300020 and a.timestamp < b.timestamp and a.id = b.id                   
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from CTE c
        where c.timestamp > a.timestamp
        and c.timestamp < b.timestamp and c.id = b.id
    )

 union
 select b.*
from CTE a
inner join CTE b
    on a.eventno = 300010 and b.eventno = 300020 and a.timestamp < b.timestamp and a.id = b.id                   
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from CTE c
        where c.timestamp > a.timestamp
        and c.timestamp < b.timestamp and c.id = b.id
    )
order by id, eventno
```

Result is:

```
id  timestamp   eventno
B   2020-01-21 13:02:45.000 300010
B   2020-01-21 13:02:90.000 300020
```

Comment: It doesn't return any rows on a table identical to the one in the question. Update: Sorry, it does. My mistake. I accidentally changed `eventid` to `id` instead of `eventno`

Comment: @Scratte, added more details to my answer. Thx